# Are body doubles ever listed in movie credits?

Tags: credits

Are body doubles (or any of their variants, such as stunt doubles or talent doubles) listed, together with the character they played, in the closing credits to a movie?

Comment: I don't know about closing credits, but it looks like it's very rare for IMDb to list body doubles along with the cast. [What It’s Like to Be a Movie Body-Double](http://www.vulture.com/2014/11/what-its-like-to-be-a-movie-body-double.html) lists several film credits for [Laura Grady](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0333607/), but IMDb only credits her body-double work on the page for *Coyote Ugly*.

Comment: Just body, or including stunt doubles?

Comment: @cde, thanks, I would be interested of knowing about stunt doubles as well and have edited the question.

Comment: Not sure if you remember the "Flashdance" controversy.  The body double for Jennifer Beals was a professional dancer, she did all of the dancing in the movie. The producers wanted this fact concealed from the public.  I believe there was some kind of controversy concerning Natalie Portman in "Black Swan " as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how common it is, but Avengers- Age of Ultron does. The Stunt Doubles for Stark, Thor, Cap, Hulk, Hawkguy, and the Vision (just as "Double" not "Stunt Double") are listed.

Black Widow has 2 Stunt Doubles AND a Body Double (Due to Scarlett Johansson's baby bump).

[image]

Of course, on the other hand, [Furious 7 was called out because they didn't credit many stunt performers](http://www.tmz.com/2015/04/22/furious-7-stunt-drivers-not-credited-ending-credits/):

> Sources directly connected with production tell us, the 2nd unit crew was responsible for all the major action ... including the parachuting car scene and the mountain road chase.
>   We're told the stunt team members feel like they were "punched in the gut" when they realized 25 members of their team -- many of whom risked their lives -- were left out of the credits.
>   And get this ... Paul Walker's 2nd unit stunt double -- who was inside a bus as it fell off a cliff -- was uncredited.

This is likely hit and miss, based on Union standards and individual contract negotiations. Length or amount of doubling required probably affects it. Body doubles for popular stars isn't exactly a dime a dozen market. Someone standing in for a single butt shot wouldn't merit the same credit as someone standing in for every punch thrown.

Comment: thanks, this is interesting...I had thought the parachuting scene was just blue screens and cgi. No wonder the Team 2 is furious here, considering how much they helped support the The Rocks', Win Diesels, and other actors coolness quotients

Comment: Does anyone find it interesting that Capt had two stunt doubles, one of whom also played as Thor's stunt double? Just a curiosity, I guess.

Comment: @Paulster2 I bet that's why Cap almost lifted the hammer.